# $F \cong \mathbb Z_p$ for some prime p where $F$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $F$ is a field and there is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ onto $F$. Show that $F \cong \mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$.

My try:
If $F$ is of finite characteristics then it prime. So by first isomorphism theorem $F \cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and we know that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z_p$ and hence the proof and on the other hand if $F$ is not of finite characteristics then its characteristics is zero and hence....

Is  it correct explanation?? Please Help!!

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
Let $\sigma$ be a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $F.$ Then what is the kernel of $\sigma?$
And what does the kernel of $\sigma$ tell us about $F?$
A further explanationcan be added if needed, hope this helps.

Comment: yes... $p\mathbb Z$ will be the kernel for a field with char. p

Comment: And can the kernel of $\sigma$ be $(0)$? Namely, can $F$ have $0$ characteristic?

Comment: if $F$ has char $0$ then it will be isomorphic to whole Z

Comment: So, is $\mathbb Z$ a *field*?

Comment: sorry..... Z is not a field

Comment: Thus you have finished the proof, right? :)

Comment: But what he's trying to prove is false, isn't it? The inclusion map $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \Bbb Q$ is a ring homomorphism, as well as the trivial map, for any field $F$.

Comment: @GPerez The condition says that the homomorphism is *surjective.*

Comment: @awllower I don't see it written. Is it because of `onto`? I didn't know this was standard for surjective. Admittedly I don't study mathematics in English either so maybe that's why.

Comment: Yes, I think the word "onto" means surjectivity. And thanks for the attention.

Comment: @awllower Huh. Shows what I know. Is it widely used? It seems so subtle for a not-subtle property.

Comment: @GPerez At least you can find this synonym on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function). Actually, the people I met oft told me that they thought *ono* is a more intuitive term.